# Qual è la differenza fra 'c'è' e 'è qui'?

Tags: word-usage, difference

So che è una domanda un po' assurda; l'uso di `c'è` o di `è qui` mi sono charissimi. Eppure dopo anni di vita all'estero, ora che mi trovo ad insegnare l'italiano a dei principianti, scopro che forse mi si sono arrugginite le parti italiane del cervello.

Una mia studentessa, alla quarta lezione, mi ha chiesto che differenza ci fosse fra `c'è` o di `è qui`, dato che in due momenti diversi avevo tradotto entrambe queste locuzioni con la stessa frase.

Così mi sono impappinato cercando di spiegare in modo semplice che si tratta due alternative per esprimere la stessa cosa, e che la prima si usa per dire che qualcosa o qualcuno sono presenti, mentre la seconda per dire dove sono.

Voi come spieghereste questa differenza in un linguaggio graduato e semplificato?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @nico!

Comment: Io direi che *c'è* può essere usato sia per *è qui* che per *è là* (e.g. Che mobili hai in ufficio? C'è una scrivania), nel senso che l'avverbio di luogo *ci* può sostituire qualsiasi luogo. Inoltre *ci* può essere usato in presenza di altri determinanti di luogo (*A casa c'è mia suocera*), mentre *qui* e *là* no (o almeno non allo stesso modo).

Comment: Per capire meglio come rispondere alla tua studentessa, in quale lingua e con quale frase hai tradotto le due costruzioni? (In tutti gli esempi che mi sono venuti in mente "è qui" è solo una risposta a una domanda. es. Dov'è il mio libro? È qui sul tavolo)

Comment: Riflettendo, ho pensato che "è qui" si può trovare in costruzioni come "è qui che". Ad esempio, potrei in futuro trovarmi con i miei nipoti a Parigi e dire: «Sapete, è qui che ho dato il mio primo bacio», frase che potrei dire anche: «Sapete, qui ho dato il mio primo bacio».

Comment: @Benedetta: uso l'inglese quando l'italiano non mi basta. In inglese "it is here" traduce entrambe le locuzioni.

Comment: Per rispondere un po' a tutti, come già suggerivo nella mia domanda, credo che la differenza sia essenzialmente fra l'essere presente in un luogo (ci) e dire dove qualcosa è (qui o lì). Non sono riuscito a spiegarlo alla mia studentessa in modo soddisfacente, ma dopo aver letto le varie idee espresse qui, e di cui sono molto grato, mi sono reso conto che spiegare queste finezze non ha senso, specie in una classe di principianti; invece basta fare degli esempi e rimandare le spiegazioni al futuro. "Ci sono 6 studenti" (6 studenti sono presenti) vs. "Gli studenti sono qui" (e non altrove).

Comment: Ma non è simile alla differenza fra *there is ...* e *... is here*?

Comment: *Qual è* si scrive senza *'*.

Comment: @nico: ai miei tempi, quando il professore faceva l'appello tra le varie cose si diceva anche *c'è* o *e' qui* per indicare la propria presenza, ma il significato vero e proprio delle due e' diverso

Comment: @nico direi che "there is" = "c'è" mentre "it's here" = "è qui". Is there some coffee? Yes there is some coffe. Is the coffe there? Yes, the coffe is here.

Answer (score 6):

Le espressioni "c'è" ed "è qui" hanno in realtà significati differenti. "C'è" si usa quando si vuol comunicare che qualcuno o qualcosa è presente o esiste, senza indicare dove o quando, oppure indicandolo vagamente. "È qui" invece si usa per dire che qualcuno o qualcosa è qui in questo momento nello stesso posto dell'interlocutore. Le due forme, dunque, non sono affatto equivalenti; infatti la prima ha più un'accezione esistenziale e generica mentre la seconda più definita e materiale. Per esempio:

1a) Dov'è Mario Rossi?
È qui (nel senso che Mario Rossi si trova esattamente dove si trova chi risponde)

1b) Dov'è il mio quaderno di italiano?
È qui (il quaderno si trova nella stessa posizione di chi risponde)

2a) C'è una macchina che va a 300 Km/h?
Sì, c'è! (significa che esiste davvero una macchina che va 300 Km/h)
2b) Insegnante: "C'è l'alunno appena arrivato?"
Sì, c'è (cioè l'alunno è presente, ma non si sa dove di preciso)

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @loopurolling!

Comment: Grazie per gli esempi, DaG! Come ho commentato sopra, mi son reso conto che in un caso come questo valgono ben più delle spiegazioni.

Comment: Negli esempi proposti 2a) e 2b) si precisa solo uno degli usi del verbo "esserci", che è usato anche per dire che una cosa è in un determinato luogo (il "ci" dell'infinito è infatti locativo). Ess. Sul tavolo ci sono i miei libri. Nella borsa c'è un regalo per te.

Comment: Per correttezza: non erano miei gli esempi, @nico, ma di loopunrolling.

Comment: Comunque @nico si scrive "qual è", non "qual'è". Purtroppo è un errore molto comune tra gli italiani.

Comment: grazie per avermi corretto... mi disiscriverò immediatamente da questo forum, ma grazie.

Comment: infatti si pososno usare anche insieme "c'è ed è qui"

Comment: Perché mai dovresti abbandonare il forum? Capita di sbagliare...